Cancel flutter timer
I want to stop the timer when I navigate to another page.
The following is my code

//imports
late Timer timer;

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget page;
    switch (selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        page = const MonitorPage();
      case 1:
        page = const ReportPage();
      case 2:
        page = const Placeholder();
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError("not found");
    }
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: [
            SafeArea(
              child: NavigationRail(
                extended: constraints.maxWidth >= 600,
                destinations: const [
                  NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                    label: Text('main'),
                  ),
                  NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                    label: Text('report'),
                  ),
                  NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                    label: Text("setting"),
                  ),
                ],
                selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
                onDestinationSelected: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (selectedIndex == 0) {
                      timer.cancel(); // here I'd like to cancel the timer
                    }
                    selectedIndex = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                child: page,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}


class _MonitorPageState extends State<MonitorPage> {
  late String _time;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _time =
        "${DateTime.now().year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${DateTime.now().month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${DateTime.now().day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')} ${DateTime.now().hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${DateTime.now().minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${DateTime.now().second.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}";
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) { // here i set the timer variable
      _updateTime(); //just updating time
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
}
}

I was expecting to cancel the timer, but it gave me this message.

======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following LateError was thrown while handling a gesture:
LateInitializationError: Field 'timer' has not been initialized.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      timer (package:TPSEM_pocket/main.dart)
#1      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:TPSEM_pocket/main.dart:184:23)
#2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1203:30)
#3      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:TPSEM_pocket/main.dart:182:19)
#4      _NavigationRailState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/navigation_rail.dart:463:62)
#5      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1183:21)
#6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:315:24)
#7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:652:11)
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:309:5)
#9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:7)
#10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:670:9)
#11     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:98:12)
#12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:143:9)
#13     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:633:13)
#14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:141:18)
#15     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:127:7)
#16     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:495:19)
#17     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:475:22)
#18     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:430:11)
#19     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:420:7)
#20     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:383:5)
#21     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:330:7)
#22     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:299:9)
#23     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:328:13)
#24     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:429:7)
#25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:262:31)
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#0c5e3
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: possible
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(115.5, 71.5)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(115.5, 19.5)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
====================================================================================================


this is the point => LateInitializationError: Field 'timer' has not been initialized.
I tried to use a state variable and set it to timer then cancel it in onDestinationSelected(right before changing the selectedIndex variable), butt it didn't work either.
How could I fix it? Thanks.

In this case you can dispose your timer variable in dispose method like this.
  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }


Try the below code to access the timer, pass the reference object to the Monitor page can use the state management approach for accessing the timer across the pages.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  
  Timer? timer;
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget page;
    switch (selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        page = MonitorPage(timer);
      case 1:
        page = const ReportPage();
      case 2:
        page = const Placeholder();
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError("not found");
    }
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: [
            SafeArea(
              child: NavigationRail(
                extended: constraints.maxWidth >= 600,
                destinations: const [
                  NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                    label: Text('main'),
                  ),
                  NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                    label: Text('report'),
                  ),
                  NavigationRailDestination(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                    label: Text("setting"),
                  ),
                ],
                selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
                onDestinationSelected: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (selectedIndex == 0) {
                      timer?.cancel(); // here I'd like to cancel the timer
                    }
                    selectedIndex = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                child: page,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

class MonitorPage extends StatefulWidget {
  Timer? timer;
  MonitorPage(this.timer,{super.key});

  @override
  State<MonitorPage> createState() => _MonitorPageState();
}

class _MonitorPageState extends State<MonitorPage> {
  late String _time;
 

  @override
  void initState() {
    _time =
        "${DateTime.now().year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${DateTime.now().month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${DateTime.now().day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')} ${DateTime.now().hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${DateTime.now().minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${DateTime.now().second.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}";
    widget.timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) { // here i set the timer variable
      _updateTime(); //just updating time
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}

